# DataGrid in Avalonia UI for Linux does not show up when app is running

Tags: c#, xaml, .net-core, avaloniaui

I'm running Avalonia UI on .NET Core for Linux (Fedora).
I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.nequalsonelifestyle.com/2019/06/13/avalonia-datagrid-getting-started/) for the DataGrid, but honestly I've added the package with the following command, instead of manually updating the `.csproj`.

```
dotnet add package Avalonia.Controls.DataGrid
```

After a `dotnet restore` and a `dotnet run`, I can't see any DataGrid.
Anyway xaml

```
<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Items="{Binding People}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

and ViewModel look fine.

```
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        People = new ObservableCollection<Person>(GenerateMockPeopleTable());
    }
```

How can I find what is going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I forgot to apply the `DataGrid` style in the App.xaml (because I'm used to WPF in Windows where the `DataGrid` is a standard Control):

```
    <StyleInclude Source="avares://Avalonia.Controls.DataGrid/Themes/Default.xaml"/>
```

The [tutorial](https://www.nequalsonelifestyle.com/2019/06/13/avalonia-datagrid-getting-started/) clearly states this step, so in conclusion I only changed the way to add the package in the project, just to get last version of the package reference.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Avalonia" Version="0.9.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Avalonia.Controls.DataGrid" Version="0.9.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Avalonia.Desktop" Version="0.9.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Avalonia.ReactiveUI" Version="0.9.9" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Aside for the version number, which obvioulsy changes with time, I can confirm that all is perfect in the above said tutorial.