# ICollectionView could not be found from Studio Code on .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, avaloniaui

I have a `XAML` and a `MVVM` showing a `DataGrid` with an `ObservableCollection`.
All working and OK (more details in my previous, already answered by myself, [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61428430/datagrid-in-avalonia-ui-for-linux-does-not-show-up-when-app-is-running)).

Now I'm trying to add a filter and I'd like to follow @mark-heath [tutorial](https://markheath.net/post/list-filtering-in-wpf-with-m-v-vm).

My project build throws the following

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ICollectionView' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

even though I did include the [documented namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.icollectionview?view=netcore-3.1).

```
using System.ComponentModel;
```

about which Studio Code shows `Unnecessary using directive` instead.
My .csproj is on .NET Core 3.0

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
```

The problem seems to be related with how I add the assembly reference.

```
dotnet add package WindowsBase
```

It restores the package using .NET Framework, but maybe this is wrong because I'm on .NET Core and on **Linux**.

Which is the correct way? Aside from the "you can't do that" answer... Maybe is there **another**, equivalent package to add... from **Avalonia UI**? Anyone knows or uses it?

### Searching on Avalonia UI github and asking on gitter

I see there was an already closed [github issue](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/2243) about that, so maybe is there a solution now? (I'm asking on Avalonia UI [gitter channel](https://gitter.im/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia?at=5ea69d4e94ac2758e30eab0a) too)

Comment: Have you considered using [DynamicData](https://github.com/reactiveui/DynamicData) instead of CollectionViewSource? It's a portable solution that's also way more flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - even in WPF and on Windows - the tutorial is wrong as per my [comment](https://markheath.net/post/list-filtering-in-wpf-with-m-v-vm#comment-4891765340) there:

> you need to bind to the `ICollectionView` and not to the
>   `ObservableCollection` to see the filtering effect.

So, the view must be fixed as follows

```
<DataGrid Items="{Binding PeopleView}"
```

Now, back to the question on Linux and in Avalonia UI.

As suggested by [Steven Kirk](https://gitter.im/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia?at=5ea6bba694ac2758e30f1729), I've looked at github [DevTools source](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/src/Avalonia.Diagnostics/Diagnostics/ViewModels/ControlDetailsViewModel.cs#L30-L32) in avalonia, that does filtering in the view model, and this clue does the trick.

So I declare `PeopleView` in the view model

```
public DataGridCollectionView PeopleView { get; }
```

as a `DataGridCollectionView` which is included in the needed namespace

```
using Avalonia.Collections;
```

and I can finally  implement the filter

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    People = new ObservableCollection<Person>(GenerateMockPeopleTable());
    PeopleView = new DataGridCollectionView(People);
    PeopleView.Filter = o => String.IsNullOrEmpty(Filter) ? true : ((Person)o).FirstName.Contains(Filter); 

}
```